# Staging awkward length arrays in shared memory

Tags: c, cuda, opencl, gpu-shared-memory

`x` is an array of length `N` in global memory operated on by a CUDA/OpenCL kernel of `k` blocks each of `w` threads (so `k = ceil(N/w)`). Each block in the kernel has a local shared array `xlocal` of length `w`. The task is for each block to load their chunk of `x` into `xlocal`.

If `w` exactly divides `N` then we can do this:

```
int lid = threadIdx.x;
int gid = threadIdx.x + (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x);
xlocal[lid] = x[gid];
```

If not then we have `w - N % w` redundant threads in the last block. How should we deal with them? I can think of the following options:

1. Allocate a larger length for `x`. i.e., allocate `k*w` elements instead of `N`. This is useful because the code above will just work. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a `realloc` equivalent in CUDA or OpenCL.
2. Do a range check before loading. This is good because we don't need to mess around with the allocation of `x`. But it's annoying to add work to the majority of threads just because of an edge condition.

   ```
    if (gid < N) xlocal[lid] = x[gid];
   ```
3. Load from `x` modulo `N` so that the redundant threads wrap around:

   ```
    xlocal[lid] = x[gid%N];
   ```

Any other thoughts on tackling this problem?

---

### Some benchmarking:

Here are some results comparing option (2) rangecheck (in blue) against option (3) loading modulo `N` (in red).

We fix a block size of 32 threads and vary `N` from 45.6k to 45.6k+32 to give 0 to 32 redundant threads in the last block, respectively. The test runs a simple kernel that preloads a shared array from global memory. The graph on the left (right) loads one (three) element(s) per thread. I compiled with CUDA 3.2.16 flags `-O2` and ran on a Tesla M2070 card.

[image: runtime]

Comment: I didn't expect this much difference. Surprising. I was more concerned about the structure of the code. But this seem something everybody should pay attention too. Good to know for the future. I assume you went with option 2 then :). Thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can allocate larger `x` from the host. Then you should think about the additional copy time that might get introduced for no use, plus the memory space. Also this will make your code lose it meaning and structure.
2. Integer comparison is very cheap. As long as there is no warp divergence for the bulk of warps, which is the case here, even conditionals aren't a too expensive in CUDA kernels.
3. With this option you are adding the extra work of calculating `gid % N` to each thread, which is exactly what you are trying to avoid, plus again additional copy from global memory (that might not hurt much because copy might be coalesced, but still).

In my opinion 2 (or maybe 3) is your best option
you would only add a couple of instructions to each thread. Not something to worry about that much considering your code will remain clear and self explanatory.

You should avoid option 1.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this. I think your gut feeling for (2) is sensible, although I might take some time to benchmark (2) vs. (3).

Comment: I think messing up your code just to save a few instructions per thread is not worth it. More important is having a code that clear, easy to maintain and debug and also reusable.